# How do I find out the origin of an image?

Tags: photos, search-engine

I found this image. It's familiar but I don't know who painted it.

[image]

What's the best way to research this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nothing to do with apple products.

Comment: Thank you for your help, is IT possible to help me find another art

Comment: We helped you, by showing you how to do it below. Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day; teach a man to fish… he will ask where to find the bait shop...

Answer (score 3):

*Probably still off-topic, but I've tried to turn this into an answerable question, more dependant on technique than the specifics of the image in question*

You can reverse-search any image, by uploading it to Google Images, or adding the URL of an online picture.

Go to https://images.google.com & click on the Camera icon.

[image]

From there you can Paste a URL or upload a picture from your computer.

From the results you can quickly hone down the source of your picture - in this case that it is one of many copies of a painting by Claude Monet; Antibes, view of Salis.

Hand-painted copies [sell for about £300](http://www.overstockart.com/painting/antibes-view-of-salis2?option_id=2746).
The original, on the other hand, was [sold at Sotheby's this year](http://www.sothebys.com/en/auctions/ecatalogue/2015/impressionist-modern-art-evening-sale-l15002/lot.8.html) for £8.7 million